# asp.net mvc best practice to vary autofac components based on environments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control, autofac, webdeploy

I have an asp.net mvc 4 application working with a simple dependency being resolved by autofac.  The dependency in this case is an IEmailSender whose implementation I want to vary based on development vs test vs production builds.  For example, the development(debug) build would send the email using one implementation, but production uses say amazon SES to send email.

What is the best practice way to vary the container dependencies in the global.asax file based on environment?  I know I can use web.config transformation with web deploy and then read the web.config value to determine the environment and then "switch" the build configuration based on environment, but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the way you have described using the web config and environment transforms, as this is its primary purpose - to determine behaviour in different environments. You may also end up with more environments that just debug (test) and release (production).

The alternative could be to use [conditional build statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`. I would not recommend this approach however as you run out of build configurations pretty quickly if suddenly you have a new environment.